# MySQL - Select all rows where an N quantity of distinct records are at

Tags: mysql, sql, select, distinct-values

I have a table with addresses, dates and some other info.

I want to select an `N` unique quantity of addresses, and of that `N` records, I want to select everything from all the rows where that address is, because the address is not a unique value in that column.

```
Date      |     Address       |    MoreInfo
1/2/2000  |   123 SUPER LN    |   SOME MORE BORING INFO
2/3/2000  |   123 SUPER LN    |   SOME MORE BORING INFO
5/3/2000  |   567 AWESOME ST  |   SOME MORE BORING INFO
5/26/2000 |   567 AWESOME ST  |   SOME MORE BORING INFO
7/2/2000  |   987 SUPER LN    |   SOME MORE BORING INFO
8/3/2000  |   1100 BORING DR  |   SOME MORE BORING INFO
11/7/2000 |   1100 BORING DR  |   SOME MORE BORING INFO
1/5/2001  |   564 SUPER LN    |   SOME MORE BORING INFO
```

So for that data, I would like to get, say 3 different addresses, (`123 SUPER LN, 567 AWESOME ST, 987 SUPER LN`) and get everything from all the rows those 3 addresses are at.

I had a query:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE my_condition = true
GROUP BY address
```

But this brings only 1 row per address, and I would like to get all the rows where those `N` addresses are at. Thanks!

Comment: The wording of your question is somewhat confusing.  Can you add some sample data which explains what you are trying to do?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you want, can you post a sample of data (start and expected results)

Comment: Don't down vote I think his 1st language is not english it seems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
select t.*
from (select distinct address
      from my_table
      where my_condition = true
      limit 100  -- this is the N
     ) a join
     my_table t
     on a.address = t.address;
```

The first subquery gets the list of addresses.  The `join` brings back the original rows.

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thank you so much!